# How to return for webRequest from inside callback

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, google-chrome-extension, promise, async-await

I am adding an eventListener to the webRequest API, inside the callback of that, I am calling the storage API to check a value. How do I respond from inside the storage API to the webRequest API?

```
    chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
        async function(details) {
          console.log('from first callback');
          await chrome.storage.sync.get('disabled', function (value) {
            console.log('from inside of second callback');
            if (value.disabled) {
              console.log('returned false')
              return { cancel: false } // this should return from the function (details) level
            } else {
              console.log('returned true')
              return { cancel: true }
            }
          })
          console.log('still from first')
        },
        {urls: [
          "myurl"
        ]},
        ["blocking"]);
```

I have heard some about promises, but I can't figure it out. How can I achieve this?

Comment: It's impossible in Chrome because its webRequest API in blocking mode is synchronous, meaning you can't have an async listener and you can't return a Promise. The only solution is to have a global variable that you'll update on extension start and then by using chrome.storage.onUpdated listener. IIRC there are existing answers, try searching.

Comment: @wOxxOm what means IIRC?